# Java Clip slow Volume and Pan update

Tags: java

I am making a 2d Game Engine using Java. On the sound side of things, I'm using the JavaSE standard Clip library to produce sound.

I've decided to create a basic 3D sound system. It worked, but has some flaws. The biggest one is  the big latency of FloatControl changes - Volume and Pan, that is used to create the 3D effect.

Both Volume and Pan is updated on every frame, however, the changes does not occur gradually, it seems the changes are applied every second.

Is there anything I can do to increase the Floatcontrol changes updates? Any library to accomplish this?

My SoundClip class:

```
private static final float NO_PAN_CHANGE = 0.0f;
private Clip clip;
private FloatControl gainControl;
private boolean dead = false;
private long clipTime;
private boolean isPaused = false;

public SoundClip (String path) {
        
        try {
            
            InputStream audioSrc = SoundClip.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
            InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(audioSrc);
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);
            AudioFormat baseFormat = ais.getFormat();
            
            AudioFormat decodeFormat = new AudioFormat(
                    AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    16,
                    baseFormat.getChannels(), 
                    baseFormat.getChannels() * 2, 
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    false
            );
            
            AudioInputStream dais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodeFormat, ais);
            
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(dais);
            
            gainControl = (FloatControl)clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            
            clip.addLineListener(new LineListener()
            {
                public void update(LineEvent evt)
                {
                    if (evt.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP)
                    {
                        if (!isPaused){
                            evt.getLine().close();
                            dead = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public void play() {
        
        if (clip == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        stop();
        
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        while(!clip.isRunning()) {
            clip.start();
        }
    }

public void setVolume(float value) {
        gainControl.setValue(value);
    }

public void setPan(float pan)
    {
        if (pan < -1f) {
            pan = -1f;
        }
        if (pan > 1f) {
            pan = 1f;
        }
        
        if ((clip == null) || (pan == NO_PAN_CHANGE)) 
        {
            FloatControl panControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN);
            panControl.setValue(pan);
        } else if (clip.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.BALANCE)) {
            FloatControl balControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.BALANCE);
            balControl.setValue(pan);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Pan or Balance controls available");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I don't know if you've already solved it, but it seems to have something to do with the clip, making a clip.flush(); it seems to update it, but it makes a clicking noise, which I'm still thinking of a solution.

Comment: @FelipeMoraes I didn't found a solution using these standard libraries. I've moved upon this issue and now i'm learning how to use OpenAL instead - the right way to implemend proper 3D sound.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [FloatControl#shift](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/FloatControl.html#shift(float,float,int)) method instead.

As per docs

> Changes the control value from the initial value to the final value linearly over the specified time period, specified in microseconds. This method returns without blocking; it does not wait for the shift to complete. An implementation should complete the operation within the time specified. The default implementation simply changes the value to the final value immediately.

You might also want to check other methods on `FloatControl`, such as: [getUpdatePeriod](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/FloatControl.html#getUpdatePeriod())

> Obtains the smallest time interval, in microseconds, over which the control's value can change during a shift. The update period is the inverse of the frequency with which the control updates its value during a shift. If the implementation does not support value shifting over time, it should set the control's value to the final value immediately and return -1 from this method.

> Returns:
> update period in microseconds, or -1 if shifting over time is unsupported

In case your control don't support shifting, you can wrap the audio input stream with your own and implement it there. Seems that [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128094456/https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21691/algorithm-to-pan-audio) question addresses that.

Comment: It seems that Volume, Pan and Balance FloatControls doesn't support shitft, getUpdatePeriod always returning -1 for all my FloatControls. I am able to pan the audio to left and right and adjust the volume to create a pseudo 3D audio, the problem is the latency between each update of volume and pannel changes.

Comment: Sounds like you need to get a control that does implement it.